# SQL Collect posts by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a table logging updates.

I would like to list the logs based on its date and status - collected so if more then one post has same date and status it should be listed togheter as collected to that date. My question is how should the SQL-query be written to get the proper front-end layout I am looking for:

Table / Column layout

```
Date                   Status          Product
2016-02-01              1              Car
2016-02-01              1              House
2016-02-01              2              Car
2016-02-01              2              Car
2016-02-01              2              House
2016-03-02              3              House
2016-03-02              2              House
```

Layout I want in front-end:

```
Date               2016-02-01     Status   1
Car 
House

Date               2016-02-01     Status 2
Car
Car
House

Date               2016-03-02     Status 3
House

Date               2016-03-02     Status 2
House
```

EDIT: Database used; MySQL

**EDIT #2: Solved;**

```
sElEcT ttt.col1,ttt.col2,ttt.col3
from
    (
    SeLeCt tt.xx as 'col1',tt.dte,tt.col3,if(tt.col3!='',tt.dte,'') as 'col2' FrOm 
    (

        select * from
        (
        SELECT 
            'Date' as 'xx', `Date` as 'dte', CONCAT('Status ',Status) as 'col3' ,Status,count(Status) as 'ord'
        FROM
            myDB
        GROUP BY `Date`,Status

        UNION all

        SELECT Product as 'xx',`Date` as 'dte','',Status,0 FROM myDB

        ) t order by t.dte,t.Status, t.ord Desc,t.xx

    ) tt 
) ttt
```

Comment: Use the 'group by' option

Comment: What do you mean by "collected"?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL or some other platform?

Comment: @AndrewMonks MySQL